# How to combine bar chart and line graph in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a chart which has both bars and line chart based on data found in the code below, the bar chart to show side by side bars of documented and eligible, and the line chart to show (on a secondary axis?) Percentage coverage. The code below however does not yet work for the line chart, please assist?

#### Edited

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat = data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
           Monthly = c("22-Mar","22-Apr","22-May",
                       "22-Jun","22-Jul","22-Aug","22-Sep","22-Oct","22-Nov",
                       "22-Dec","23-Jan","23-Feb","23-Mar","23-Apr"),
          Eligible = c(1374L,1336L,1410L,1419L,
                       1418L,1420L,1137L,1358L,1358L,1409L,1419L,1409L,
                       1358L,1415L),
        Documented = c(1260L,1299L,1370L,1375L,
                       1376L,1380L,1116L,1332L,1332L,1386L,1401L,1381L,
                       1339L,1398L)
)

dat1 = dat %>% 
  mutate(Percentage=round(Documented/Eligible,2)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Eligible,Documented,Percentage),values_to = "values")

dat1$Monthly = factor(dat1$Monthly,
                      levels = c("22-Mar","22-Apr","22-May","22-Jun","22-Jul",
                                 "22-Aug","22-Sep","22-Oct","22-Nov","22-Dec",
                                 "23-Jan","23-Feb","23-Mar","23-Apr"))
dat1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Monthly,values,fill=name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  # Attempt at secondary plot here:
  geom_line(data = dat1 %>% filter(name=="Percentage"),aes(Monthly,values,group=name)) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9) +
  #coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a discrete variable on the x axis, so you need to add a grouping variable to define which points you want the lines to go through. You can do this by adding `group = name` inside `aes`. It would make sense to dodge the lines by the same amount as the bars, and color them appropriately too.

For the secondary axis, you need to scale your `percentage` to be on the same scale as your data (say multiply it by 1400), then reverse this transform inside `sec_axis`

```r
dat %>% 
  mutate(Percentage = 1400 * Documented / Eligible) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Eligible, Documented, Percentage)) %>%
  mutate(Monthly = factor(Monthly, levels = c("22-Mar", "22-Apr", "22-May",
                                              "22-Jun", "22-Jul", "22-Aug",
                                              "22-Sep", "22-Oct", "22-Nov",
                                              "22-Dec", "23-Jan", "23-Feb",
                                              "23-Mar", "23-Apr"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Monthly, value, fill = name, group = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = name), position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = 0.7) +
  scale_color_grey(start = 0, end = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.x/1400, labels = scales::percent)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion, but the effect was not helpful (no secondary axis (Percentage) and I only want a geom_line where the variable name=="Percentage". I am editing the above code to show the output of a second attempt with grouping by name as suggested

Comment: @TumainiKilimba see my update - you need to add a transformation to the percentage values to get them on the same scale as the actual values, then reverse this transform in the secondary axis.